# Elastic Search Highlight API highlight all macthed words

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed document like below in elastic search.

**Doc:**

```
{{"ID:1, "Cont": "yes there is a match"},
  {"ID":2, "Cont": "check this for it"} ....}
```

When I searched the document using highlight.

```
http://localhost:9200/sample/html/_search
{
    "query": 
        {"bool": {  
            "should": [{"match": {"Content": "check mate"}}]}},
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "Content" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

The output was like below.

```
"highlight": {
      "Content": ["<em>check</em> blaa", "blaa blaa<em>check</em>"]
}
```

From the highlight output it looks like **check** matched on two places but when I open the document and see there was 15 occurrence of **check** and there was also a match for **mate** in the document.

1. Is there a way to get all matched words in the highlight column i.e.) get both the check and mate of this example.

   2.Is there a way to get match occurrence count i.e.) check=15, mate=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For your first question:**

You can use the `number_of_fragments` option to get more highlight fragments. By default it is set to `2` (that's why you can see only 2 highlights). You can set it to 100 for example if you want to see more of them.

You can also set `number_of_fragments` to `0`, this will not fragment your Content to show highlights but will give your **whole** content highlighted (then you will see all highlight occurences).

Documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#_highlighted_fragments

**2nd question:**

As far as I know, I don't think that's possible... You would have to count them from the highlight result I'm affraid...

Comment: I could set `number_of_fragments:0` but the content is big(a whole HTML page) but is there a way to get only matched phrase fragments instead of the whole field and I could not give value like 100 to number_of_fragments since  I don't know how many matches I get

Comment: I don't know of any other way other than set `number_of_fragments` to a very big number like 9999999 ^^' but if you are trying to just count occurences that's not really the good way... (but I don't know waht could be the good way)

Comment: I am getting many false positive matches so I am trying to see which tokens of my query matched with the indexed document. From which I can develop an algorithm to remove the false positive matches. Let see if I can find a way to count or get all matched tokens. If not I will try your idea of setting to a large number and see :).